# Calculating $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}t^{1/2} \int_0^1 e^{-t r^2}\,d r$

Tags: integration, limits

How can we prove $\lim\limits_{t\to+\infty}t^{1/2} \int_0^1 e^{-t r^2}\,dr=0$?

The hard part is the neighourhood of $0$...

Answer (score 5):

Your limit is incorrect. A substitution $r = t^{-1/2} s$ shows:

$$\sqrt{t} \int_0^1 e^{-tr^2} \, dr = \int_0^{\sqrt{t}} e^{-s^2} \, ds \to \int_0^\infty e^{-s^2} \, ds = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.$$